# Working with two google maps

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I need some help with the following:

I am trying to get two maps to display two different things.

My problem is, on the first map I would like to click on a link in the infowindow (see this) when I do click on that link, I would like that marker to display alone on the second map at its location.
here is my code. Thank you for any help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var map;
var service;

function initialise(location) {
    console.log("location:" + location);
    var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude,   location.coords.longitude);

    var mapOption = {
        center : currentLocation,
        zoom : 14,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOption);




    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : currentLocation,
        map : map,
    });

    marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');


    //service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', performSearch);

    function handleSearchResults(results, status) {
        console.log(results)
    }

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map : map,
            position : place.geometry.location
        });



        var content = '<p><a href="/menus/gid/'+place.place_id+'/'+place.name+'">See this</a></p>'

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
            'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
            place.formatted_address + content)
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            var latitude = this.position.lat();
            var longitude = this.position.lng();
            console.log(this.position);
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        var input = $("#search").val();
        var query = (input != '' )? input : "restaurant";
        performSearch(query);
    });

    function performSearch(q){
        var request ={
            bounds: map.getBounds(),
            query:String(q)
        };
        service.textSearch(request, callback);
    }
}




function initializer() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 13,
    });

    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        browserSupportFlag = true;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : initialLocation,
                map : map,
            });
            marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
        }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        });
    }
     }

     function initializer_2() {

       var mapOption2 = {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(41.923, 12.513),
        zoom : 14,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   // need the position of marker
        //position : currentLocation,
        map : map,
    });

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas2"),    mapOption2);
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializer);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializer_2);


$(".getSearch").click(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialise);
});
});
```

Comment: You need two different map variables.

Comment: See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ooq7wcjc/) that uses two maps (one above the other).

Comment: im eventually going to place the map on a different page. my mane concern now is to have the marker alone show on the map once i click the link on the first maps info window.